# Coldfusion.MessageBox.show is throwing an error. How can I fix?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I'm working on a form, and throughought it, if someone doesnt fill in a field, or fills it in incorrectly, it is added to a cfset called `#outputString#`. I have a little function that creates a cfmessagebox then shows it using javascript. It is as follows:

```
   <cfif errorFound EQ true>
        <cfmessagebox message=#outputstring# icon="error" type="alert" title="error" name="error"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            ColdFusion.MessageBox.show("error"); 
        </script>
    </cfif>
```

However, when the form is submitted with an error, causing the `errorfound` cfset to return true, I get this error in the console:

`Uncaught ColdFusion.MessageBox.getMessageBoxObject: MessageBox object is not found for id: error`

My first thought was that I needed an "id" field, but that's apparently an invalid parameter. I'm at a loss here. Any help?

Edit: I forgot to mention, but I do import the necessary ajax for javascript

`<cfajaximport tags="cfmessagebox">`

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ea2.html

Right here it says the tag creates it, and show shows it...

Comment: on the documentation page for create, it says that "This function is equivalent to the cfmessagebox tag."

But because I know how finicky this kind of thing can be, I suppose I can try it.

Comment: Just tried it. It doesnt seem to like that either. Also I lose a few options that I get with the tag, like the icon

Comment: Change the name of the message box to anything but "error" and see if that works. There could be another DOM element with the same ID.

Comment: Don't use cfmessagebox (or any of the ColdFusion UI components). Pick a JS library and use their implementation of what you need. The ColdFusion UI stuff is wonky at best.

Comment: I second @ScottStroz's comment. Don't start down the road of using ColdFusion's UI crap.

Comment: I'm starting to learn that... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the quotes around your message variable in the `<cfmessagebox>` tag.

Should look like this:

```
<cfmessagebox message="#outputstring#" icon="error" type="alert" title="error" name="error"/>
```

I would try naming your `<cfmessagebox>` something other than "error". That name may be causing a conflict with other code on your page. Try using another name.

Comment: Nope, sorry. I changed that and I still have the same error. Probably still a good thing to include though.

Comment: I figured that probably wasn't the issue but you should still include them. View the source of your generated page and search for the string `error`. See if that shows you the issue/conflict. You might try naming your cfmessagebox something other than "error" in case it is conflicting with something else.

Comment: That could be it...  I'll give it a try later

Comment: I'm accepting. I've gone in aother direction, but you helped point me there. Thank you!